# Ansible does not locate localhost in hosts file

Tags: linux, ansible, devops

I'm using localhost in a yaml format ansible hosts file. Whenever I run the playbook I get the following warning. The playbook runs successfully by using the implicit localhost. Why does this happen and how can I correct it?

```
➜  ec2 ansible-playbook site.yml -i inventory/hosts.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

It's not clear to me why ansible reports this warning. Below is my hosts.yml contents.

```
all:
  children:
    hosts:
      localhost:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inventory format is incorrect. If you have a `children` key under `all`, then you need a child group name.  E.g.:

```
all:
  children:
    mygroupname:
      hosts:
        localhost:
```

If you don't have any subgroups, then you can just write:

```
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
```

And of course, if your only host is `localhost` you don't need an inventory file to begin with.